# If $X \hookrightarrow Y$, $X_0 \subset X$, $Y_0 \subset Y$ then $X_0 \hookrightarrow Y_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X=(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $Y=(Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ be Banach spaces such that $X \hookrightarrow Y$, that is, $X$ is continuous embedding in $Y$. In other words, $X \subset Y$ and there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\|u\|_Y \leq c\|u\|_X,\; \forall \; u \in X. \tag{1}$$

Let $X_0 \subset X$ be a closed subspace of $X$ and $Y_0 \subset Y$ be a closed subspace of $Y$. Thus, $$X_0=(X_0, ||\cdot||_X)\quad \text{and} \quad Y_0=(Y_0, ||\cdot||_Y)$$ are Banach spaces.

**Question.** It's true that $X_0 \hookrightarrow Y_0$?

What I thought is that: $X \hookrightarrow Y$ implies (by definition) that the inclusion $i: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous. But, this implies that $i: X_0 \longrightarrow Y_0$ is also continuous, that is, $X_0 \hookrightarrow Y_0$? Or should I have to have some condition on $ i(X_0) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work.  Here is a counter example: take  any two Banach spaces $Z$ and $W$, and put $X=Y=Z\oplus W$, $X_0=Z$, and $Y_0=W$.  Then there is no reason for $Z\hookrightarrow W$.